# Pandas: read_json urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>, code used to work

Tags: python, pandas, urllib

I have this code :

```
 import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/trades/tABSETH/hist?limit=5000&start=1104534000000&sort=1'
df = pd.read_json(url)
```

Recently it started to return an error :

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

But it has worked in the past, do i need to make any adjustment to this code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

raw_data = requests.get(url)
data = raw_data.json()
json_results = json.dumps(data)
raw_data_df = pd.read_json(json_results)
```

This format should help out with this issues - pd seems to have messed something up with the newest update.